# String: extract wanted character instead of removing unwanted

Tags: r, string, char

I was wandering if in R their is a function like `KeepChar("abcde....xyz", some_text)` that you feed with all the desired character that you want to keep, and returns the strings with only the desired character left in it. Here the function would only keep the letters of the alphabet in lower case. I would like something that looks like this:

```
some_text <- "Hel-_l0o W#oRr^ld"
some_text <- KeepChar("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ", some_text)
some_text
> "hello world"
```

I feel that the removing method that I am currently using `gsub("@\\w+", "", some_text)`, `tm_map(some_text, stripWhitespace)` or `str_replace_all(some_text,"[^[:graph:]]", " ")` takes a lot of time and coding line with a constant risk of forgetting to remove a specific character, especially when you already know exactly what you want to keep.

Why I ask this question is because I am coding a plateform to process sentiment analysis on texts from various sources like `twitter` and I want to make sure not to forget to remove any unwanted character.

Comment: How about using `gsub` with regex and group extraction?

Comment: why is the capital `H` and `W` kept in your example? and the space? You could do `keep_char <- "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; gsub(paste0("[^",keep_char,"]"),"",some_text)`

Comment: It's also not clear why the space is also kept if you only want to keep the chars.

Comment: Good point ! I correct it right away :)

Comment: `stringr` package might be suitable for you. `str_extract` is in there...

Comment: Almost, however, it seperate each corresponding element seperated by a white space in a different string...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle a pattern without using regex I will try this:

```
string <- "Hel-_l0o W#oRr^ld"
pattern <- "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

KeepChar = function(pattern, string){
  splitted_string <- unlist(strsplit(string, ""))
  splitted_pattern <- unlist(strsplit(pattern, ""))
  ids_string <- splitted_string %in% splitted_pattern
  return(paste(splitted_string[ids_string], sep = "", collapse = ""))
}

some_text <- KeepChar(pattern = pattern, string = string)
```

Comment: That is a relly nice function that is working like a charm !
Both answer solved my problem, however yours is even more complete.

Comment: I am glad that it helps you @YohanObadia. Even if the function works, and its output solved your problem, I can't stop seeing it as a too procedural solution. I hope there is, or will be, a package with a dedicated function!

Comment: It would be great if a package like stringr or tm integrated it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
some_text <- "Hel-_l0o W#oRr^ld"
gsub("[^[:alpha:] ]", "", some_text)#will return all characters
gsub("[^[:lower:] ]", "", some_text)#will return only lower characters alongwith space
gsub("[^[:upper:] ]", "", some_text)#will return higher case characters alongwith space
```

You can also look at the page https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html to see the matches available in R

Comment: That is perfect ! Thank you very much :)

Comment: @YohanObadia you are contradicting your self. This is also a *removing* method rather a *keeping* one, and pretty similar to what you already tried. I fail to understand how this answers your question. In other words,  this is equivalent to `str_replace_all(some_text, "[^[:alpha:] ]", "")`

Comment: In fact I wanted to only keep characters and that method does it. So in my case it is exactly what I want. However I agree that if, let say, I wanted to also keep the value `0` and `@` that would not work. If you have a more general answer, feel free to post it.